# Bower Init Register requires an interactive shell error

Tags: shell, bower, init, interactive, bower-register

[this is what I get when I use bower init](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOdrv.png)

what could be the problem??

Comment: bower verson is 1.5.3

Comment: Hello. Consider to select an answer...

Answer (score 8):

The problem is with the terminal/console you're using to.

I ran into this same problem other day, I was using Git bash as my terminal, and trying to run this command with Node.js command prompt worked normally.

Try to use **another terminal**, like **[cmder](http://cmder.net/)** (I really recommend this to **Windows users**), Node.js command prompt or even Windows cmd itself. Hope to have helped you. Best wishes!

Comment: I had to run this command first to install bower globally..
$ npm install -g bower    
https://bower.io/

Answer (score 1):

> The solution is to install GIT bash and avoid
>   using MinTTY and follow the documentation. Here is the solution:
>
> Uninstall existing GIT bash Reinstall GIT bash Set up during
>   installation:

- > Select Use Git from the Windows Command Prompt
- > Select Checkout Windows-style, commit Unix-style line endings
- > Select Use Windows' default console window

Answer (score 0):

Okay this works for sure -

1. Go to https://cygwin.com/install.html and download either the
   32 or 64 bit version of `Cygwin`.
2. Run the install and install it onto one of your drives.
3. Run the `Cygwin.bat` and you will get the same command line
   interface.
4. When you run bower init, it will work just fine. The `Mintty` that
   comes with `GIT` is broken for somethings.  Use the shell that comes
   with `Cygwin` and you will be fine.

It works for me no problem. I used the 64 bit version on a Window 8 64bit OS. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely running `C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe` and can instead run `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe` to eliminate the issue. This avoids having to install another yet another terminal.